# Creating new project displaying error in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Regards.I have some problem whenever i create new android project in eclipse,it is showing error. Error is in "R" class,i guess i am not able to create R class in my project. It is showing R with under red line when i look into MainActivity.java class.  Between,i have installed window and all the android-sdk and plug-in  cuz i had some window issue previously but now eclipse is not working with new projects. Please help me to resolve out the problem.

Comment: Which Version of OS you are using and eclipse version

Comment: did u import android.R; in your list of packages? if so delete that import clean the project and try again

Comment: clean your project and build all and then run your project otherwise click ctrl+1 it will quick fix your problem.

Comment: @sainath-I am using Window7 and Version: Juno Service Release 2

Comment: @ AndroidEnthusiastic-I have done both of them, Clean as well as Build Automatically. but nothing works

Comment: @Sanghita- I didn't import anything

Comment: Try cleaning your project and check in your resource files for any error.

Comment: Mr. Oam,I have done cleaning my project but the problem is same. I create many new android project but every time i create it,it is showing me Error with red mark under the "R" in code "R.layout.activitymain;" or every related code to it. even i cant see R class under my "gen" folder.

Comment: @Oam I've asked him to delete the import statement if u follow me, and not import the android.R

Comment: Is android `build target` is checked in project properties?

Comment: I have just resolved the problem by updating Packages through SDK-Manager. Thanks OAM,Sanghita,Sainath,AndroidEnthusiastic for your support.

Answer (score 1):

->  First close My-eclipse.

->  delete/rename existing workspace.

->  delete .android folder that exists in your Computer   User accounts.

->  Just run eclipse with Administrator Privileges.

Then problem is solved..

Comment: Seems like effective idea,But nothing happened.now i am trying to install the sdk again with new eclipse

Comment: By the Way, what does .android folder stands for in my account?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Pavan tilak for your Advice. I have resolved the problem with another method,just updated Packages.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on **Project -> Build automatically** in eclipse. This will generate new R.java file. Look into your gen-package, if the R.java is available.

Comment: I did. But the problem is same.

Comment: maybe you have a bug in your resources like layout xml or something malformed in the xmls.

Comment: No,Not possible because I create very new project. Even i cant find R.class under my "gen" folder. i clicked the folder but it is showing nothing maybe because it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to update ADT plugin by Help -> Check of Updates.

Next open Project Properties -> Java Build Path.

In 'Source' Tab must be 'gen' folder.

'Order and Export' Tab must be in this order:

1. projectName/src
2. projectName/gen
3. Android x.x
4. Android Private Libraries
5. Android Dependencies

!!! 4 & 5 must be selected in checkbox !!!

Comment: Yes,It is in that Order. Mr.Falcon

Answer (score 0):

First of all just check if by mistake you have imported amndroid.R in your imports. If yes then remove that line and clean and refresh you project. IF the probem still exists try adding few widgets as button or textview or anything in your main xm and clean it rebuild it and try to run. If you do some change in xml file you R.java gets generated automatically.

Comment: No,there is no android.R import. Added textview but still failed.

Comment: Try adding everything in your main.xml save it and cean the project refresh the project and restart the eclipse.

Comment: Then i feel you have some problem in your android plugin. In your Help menu at the top of the screen check for updates or install new software in that update your eclipse and adt both. I think that will help.

Comment: Try importing any project and check if still the same problem exists in the imported project.

Comment: Yes,I am getting the error on importing some other project too.

Comment: Then you need to change ur eclipse or android. Try changing it one by one and upgrading it to new versions.

Comment: Finally,I am Done. If somebody may want to know in future then I have just installed my outdated package,Updated them through SDK-Manager and it is fixed now. Thank you mr. New Bie and all other for your Support. Cheers